# WebSocket4Net Client Message Size

Tags: c#, networking, websocket

I want to communicate a [WebSocket4Net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket4Net/) Client with a server implemented with [AlchemyWebSockets](http://alchemywebsockets.net/). Basically I want to send strings messages between them. The issue is that when the string message is bigger than 504 bytes it arrives with errors.
I wonder if this type of communication imposes a restriction on the size of the message.

In the example below the client sends a message to the server containing 1000 characters. The server always receive a message consisting of 504 letters 'a' then 4 to 6 random characters then 496 letters 'a'. I tried to send 2000 'a's and the server receives some amount of 'a' at the beginning then a lot of random characters and some 'a' at the end.

**Client.**

```
Socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9988");

//a block of 1000 letters
string a = new string('a', 1000);
Socket.Send(a);
```

**Server.**

```
var server = new WebSocketServer(9988, IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"))
              {
                   OnReceive = OnReceive,
                   OnSend = OnSend,
                   OnConnected = OnConnect,
                   OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect,
                   TimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
              };

public void OnReceive(UserContext context)
{
    string message = context.DataFrame.ToString();

    //more code to proccess message
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could test this example and send me some feedback. Thanks

**EDIT 1:**
I tried to use `Alchemy.WebSocketClient` for the client implementation. This time the error is different, I sent 1000 bytes and received 506, there are no random bytes and just one part of the message.